# suitescript adding item sublist to itempricing sublist - improve performance

Tags: javascript, optimization, transactions, netsuite, suitescript

I am writing a script in NetSuite's javascript SuiteScript that takes the item sublist from a quote or sales order, and on edit or create, adds or updates those items on the item pricing sublist on the customer record.

So 2 lists I am comparing (rec.itempricing and newSoQuote.item), then updating rec.itempricing

My question: I am having performance issues with having the triple for loops (obviously); how can I combine some of the lines in those for loops to reduce execution time?

Code below:

```
function userEventBeforeSubmit(type){
var currentUserRole = nlapiGetRole();
if (type != 'create' && type != 'edit')
    return;

if (currentUserRole != 1037 && currentUserRole != 1064)
    return;

var newSoQuote = nlapiGetNewRecord();
var custInternalId = newSoQuote.getFieldValue('entity');
var soItemsCount = newSoQuote.getLineItemCount('item');
var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('customer',custInternalId); //load customer record
var quotedPrice, duplicate, itemType;
var itemPricingCount;

for (var i = 1; i <= soItemsCount; i++) {
    duplicate = false;
    itemType = newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item', 'itemtype', i);
    if(itemType == 'InvtPart') {
        itemPricingCount = rec.getLineItemCount('itempricing');
        //get the rate (unit price)
        quotedPrice = newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item', 'rate', i);
        //check for duplicate
        for (var j = 1; j <= itemPricingCount; j++) {
            //if we find a match on itempricing list
            if (newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item','item',i) == rec.getLineItemValue('itempricing', 'item', j)){
                rec.selectLineItem('itempricing', j);
                rec.setCurrentLineItemValue('itempricing', 'price', quotedPrice); //update price
                rec.commitLineItem('itempricing'); //commit the line item
                j = itemPricingCount + 1;
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }
        for (var k = 1; k < i; k++) {
            if (newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', i) == newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', k))
                duplicate = true;
        }
        if (!duplicate) { //if not on the itempricing sublist adding new item
            rec.selectNewLineItem('itempricing'); //select a new line on the item price sublist
            rec.setCurrentLineItemValue('itempricing', 'item', newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', i)); //select an item
            rec.setCurrentLineItemValue('itempricing', 'level', -1); //select 'custom' level
            rec.setCurrentLineItemValue('itempricing', 'currency', 1); //select currency
            rec.setCurrentLineItemValue('itempricing', 'price', quotedPrice); //input price
            rec.commitLineItem('itempricing'); //commit the line item
        }
    }
}
nlapiSubmitRecord(rec);  //submit the record
```

}

I already moved all variable declarations out of the for loops, but it seems like everything else is necessary...

Thanks all, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the findLineItemValue method on the rec object.  It would work as follows:

```
var lookForItem = newSoQuote.getLineItemValue('item','item',i);
var foundIndex = rec.findLineItemValue('itempricing','item',lookForItem);
/* if foundIndex is -1, the item was not found, exlist it would be the row index in sublist  */
if(foundIndex==-1) {
    rec.selectNewLineItem('itempricing');
    //...  and set the rest of your sublist values.
    rec.commitLineItem('itempricing'); //commit the line item
}
```

Let me know if you need addition clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you're using `selectNewLineItem`, `commitLineItem` and 'selectLineItem` within a for loop. These operations rely on relatively slow DOM manipulations and ajax transfers. Often, this is unavoidable.

The only faster way to accomplish what you need would be to use a back-end event script, which can manipulate the sublist without all the DOM/GUI manipulation. It's a somewhat different approach, since the scripts only run before the GUI is rendered, or in-between saves.

P.S. For a small, potential speed gain, try disabling event triggers on `setCurrentLineItemValue`. To disable, you need to set one of the method parameters to `false`